# eliminating quotation marks from an expression

Tags: r

I have the following variables between " and "

```
A<-"Dxi2 , Dxu2 , Dxa2 , Dxb2 , Dxc2 , Dxd2"
```

How could I take out the " as to obtain

```
A<-data.frame(Dxi2 , Dxu2 , Dxa2 , Dxb2 , Dxc2 , Dxd2)
```

or

```
A <-c(Dxi2 , Dxu2 , Dxa2 , Dxb2 , Dxc2 , Dxd2)
```

Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think what you actually want is:

```
as.data.frame(mget(unlist(strsplit(A, "\\s*,\\s*"))))
```

which will produce the data frame from the variables referenced by `A`.  However, if you want to get the expression, you can:

```
parse(text=paste0("A <- data.frame(", A, ")"))[[1]]
```

which produces:

```
A <- data.frame(Dxi2, Dxu2, Dxa2, Dxb2, Dxc2, Dxd2)
```

You can also evaluate it to get the data frame, but if you're going to do this, I would recommend the `mget` solution:

```
eval(parse(text=paste0("A <- data.frame(", A, ")")))
```

Comment: Wouldn't you need to use `strsplit` or something before using `mget`?

Comment: Thank you, would you happen to know how to obtain only A <- data.frame(Dxi2 , Dxu2 , Dxa2 , Dxb2 , Dxc2 , Dxd2) without "expression" and eliminating the ( and the end ) as to use A in another expression

Comment: @Barnaby, I think that is what the second line of code does (notice the `[[1]]` at the end.  And what do you mean "use A in another expression"?  Are you going to copy and paste the line?  Or do you want the expression `data.frame(Dxi2, Dxu2, Dxa2, Dxb2, Dxc2, Dxd2)` stored in `A`?  And how do you intend to use it?  With `eval`?

Comment: Sorry did not seed the edit before I wrote the prior comment it is the first expression of you answer. Many thanks again